# Uso de Provider en Angular sin afectar otro provide ya existente

Tags: angular

Necesito agregar un código en mi `app.module.ts` sin mover nada del actual ya que lo necesito por que uso un SSO para autenticación y si lo elimino la app solicita autenticación y necesito agregar un Http_Interceptor en mi module.

`ANGULAR VERSION > 11`

Actual que no puedo quitar:

```
providers: [{
    provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
    useFactory: initializeKeycloak,
    multi: true,
    deps: [KeycloakService],
  }],
```

Necesito agregar esto sin mover lo demás y que me siga sirviendo lo anterior.

```
{
   provide : HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
   useClass: AuthInterceptor,
   multi   : true,
},
```

Intente de esta manera pero no cargan las paginas se quedan en blanco al hacer esto:

```
providers: [{
    provide: [APP_INITIALIZER,HTTP_INTERCEPTORS],
    useFactory: initializeKeycloak,
    useClass: AuthInterceptor,
    multi: true,
    deps: [KeycloakService],
  }],
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes añadir múltiples providers armando un array:

```
providers: [
  {
    provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
    useFactory: initializeKeycloak,
    multi: true,
    deps: [KeycloakService]
  },
  {
    provide : HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
    useClass: AuthInterceptor,
    multi   : true
  },
  ...
],
...
```